# Why is Gradle not finding 'project()' method in subproject dependencies?

Tags: groovy, gradle

I'm both a Gradle newb and a Groovy newb. Unfortunately I don't get the luxury of learning them separately.

The error:

```
Build file '/shave-and-a-haircut-two-bits/parentproject/childproject/build.gradle' line: 9

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':commonstuff:services'.
> Could not find method project() for arguments [[org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs, ... 
DefaultExternalModuleDependency{group='org.codehaus.jettison', name='jettison', version='null', configuration='default'},
DefaultExternalModuleDependency{group='org.apache.cxf', name='cxf-rt-security', version='null', configuration='default'}]] on project ':commonstuff:services'.
```

So the lists of dependencies seem to be working and are available to the subproject at least. Otherwise I doubt we would get such a detailed complaint.

The subproject build file:

```
apply plugin: 'war'

description = 'services'
dependencies {
    ...        
    compile project(rootProject.ext.cxf)
    compile project(rootProject.ext.springframework)    
    ...

}
```

Note the use of the Spring `dependencyManagement` plug-in and the use of Lists stored as properties in the root project to manage groups of dependencies, CXF included. No versions are specified as `dependencyManagement` should handle that... right?

Clue please?

Comment: I'm guessing, but I would try `project(rootProject).ext.cxf`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are actually two methods, called *project* in [`Project`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Project.html) API. One accepts a String *path* and the second one overrides the first and accepts a Closure as a second argument. What you actually passed as an argument is a List, so there's no method that matches the given argument. It seems that in this particular case:

```
compile (rootProject.ext.cxf)
```

will do what you need to be done.

Comment: I had to look at that for a few seconds to notice the difference. ;-) Yep. That works. Thank you.

Comment: Adding to what @Opal has said, the `project(...)` notation is only used when the dependency is a local project. In the case of cxf and spring etc I can only assume that these are not local projects in your build which is why you shouldn't use the `project(...)` notation.

Comment: @LanceJava, these are just libraries provided from a map. Feel free to update my answer.